# one-liner to remove certain letters from end of string using rsplit?

Tags: python, string, methods

I need a one liner that turns `"helloabcdabcababd"` into `"hello"`. Basically, it takes a string or list of strings and uses rsplit to find the point where the characters aren't a b c or d and deletes everything after. Is there a way for rsplit() to take multiple different letters?

I'm stuck and here's what I currently have

```py
def cleaning_right(string):
    print([i.rsplit(" ") for i in string.rsplit() if i not in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]])
```

Comment: `s.rstrip('abcd')`?

Comment: Ah that's what I was looking for, wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```py
def cleaning_right(string):
  return ''.join(re.split(r'[abcd]*$', string))
```